# ThreeJS multiple materials or shaders on mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

Currently I'm working with ThreeJS and I need to combine the shadermaterial, because I'm using a custom shader that combines several textures into a single one, with the meshphongmaterial, since i don't want to lose all the work (lights and reflection) that the shader from meshphongmaterial does.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather easy, I just took the shader code from the phong material and added my custom code in the section the texel variable is assigned.